# CSS, JavaScript style dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, styles

Some help would be much appreciated. It's too much information to sink in for a new developer here

I am trying to make a dynamic table created like this:

```
function myFunction2() {
    var img = new Image();
    var table = document.getElementById("Table1");
    var row = table.insertRow(table.length);
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    row.insertCell(i);
     }
    //Add Txt
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "insert";
    //Add Images
    var Sport = document.createElement("IMG");
    Sport.setAttribute("src", "Images/ball.png");
    Sport.setAttribute("div", "Sport");
    row.insertCell(0).appendChild(Sport);


    //Add drop-down list
    var dd = document.createElement("select");
    dd.name = "SportSelector";
    dd.id = "id" + document.getElementById('Table1').rows.length;
    dd.options[dd.length] = new Option("Soccer", "value1");
    dd.options[dd.length] = new Option("Basket", "value2");
    dd.options[dd.length] = new Option("Hockey", "value3");
    dd.setAttribute("onchange", "GetSport(this)");
    row.insertCell(1).appendChild(dd);
    //Done
}
```

So far so good, But right about now I am stuck trying to resize the table and I have no clue How to do this. For now I am trying to adjust Col(0) which should only contain an icon.

I have tried to give it class name "Sport" and in CSS have this:

```
 Sport {
    width: 20 px;
    margin-right: 30%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

But this does not work. Any pointer to what I need to do would be great ?

Edit:

Ok so I went with the suggestion from Ivan86 , I have a couple of questions?

Looks like your edit broke another part of my code

```
function GetSport(val) {
    var x = val.id;
    var x = x.replace("id", "");
    var table =  document.getElementById("Table1")
    table.rows[x - 1].cells[0].innerHTML = "<img src='Images/ball.png'/>";
    //alert("The input value has changed. The new value is: " + val.id);
}
```

This code was supposed to also change the img file based on the selection in the drop-down. Any suggestion to how to fix ?

Also this part of your suggestion I did not add:

```
<table id="Table1">
<tr>
    <td colspan="12">OLD ROW</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction2()" value="add a new row" />
```

And the txt "insert" was not supposed to be any part of the code, I updated to this:

```
function myFunction2()
{
var img = new Image();
var table = document.getElementById("Table1");
var row = table.insertRow(table.length);
// make a cell array
var cells = [];

for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
  // add the cell to the table and to the cell array
  cells.push(row.insertCell(i));
}
//Add Txt

//Add Images
var Sport = document.createElement("IMG");
Sport.setAttribute("src", "Images/ball.png");
Sport.setAttribute("height", "20px");
Sport.setAttribute("width", "20px");
cells[0].appendChild(Sport);
// to add class
cells[0].classList.add('Sport');
// to add CSS to the first cell
cells[0].style.width = '15px';
// create margin-right effect
cells[1].style.padding = '0 0 0 0px';


//Add drop-down list
var dd = document.createElement("select");
dd.name = "SportSelector";
dd.id = "id" + document.getElementById('Table1').rows.length;
dd.options[dd.length] = new Option("Soccer", "value1");
dd.options[dd.length] = new Option("Basket", "value2");
dd.options[dd.length] = new Option("Hockey", "value3");
dd.setAttribute("onchange", "GetSport(this)");
cells[1].appendChild(dd);
//Done
}
```

See the Pen [My project](https://codepen.io/frederik84/pen/LeqGzz/) by frederik ([@frederik84](https://codepen.io/frederik84)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Your add image stuff is making this `<img src="Images/ball.png" div="Sport"></img>` is that intentional?

Comment: It was not my intention to add the class to the img but rather the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the `inserted columns` in an `array` so you can easily target them later.

I added a `width` to the `table` and some basic example `CSS`.

I also didn't use the `class` `Sport` for the cell styling, but I did add the `class` `sport` to the `column`if you need it that way.

**Here is the code:**

**Note:** `margins` don't work on `table cells`, you would need to simply change the `cell width` or possibly use `padding-right`. But your best approach in my opinion is to set `padding-left` on the second column.

```js
function myFunction2()
{
    var img = new Image();
    var table = document.getElementById("Table1");
    var row = table.insertRow(table.length);
    // make a cell array
    var cells = [];
    
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
      // add the cell to the table and to the cell array
      cells.push(row.insertCell(i));
    }
    //Add Txt

    //Add Images
    var Sport = document.createElement("IMG");
    Sport.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-3d-printer-icon-set/256/Model.png");
    Sport.setAttribute("height", "20px");
    Sport.setAttribute("width", "20px");
    cells[0].appendChild(Sport);
    // to add class
    cells[0].classList.add('Sport');
    // to add CSS to the first cell
    cells[0].style.width = '20px';
    cells[0].style.border= '1px solid #09f';
    // create margin-right effect
    cells[1].style.padding = '0 0 0 20px';


    //Add drop-down list
    var dd = document.createElement("select");
    dd.name = "SportSelector";
    dd.id = "id" + document.getElementById('Table1').rows.length;
    dd.options[dd.length] = new Option("Soccer", "soccer");
    dd.options[dd.length] = new Option("Basket", "basket");
    dd.options[dd.length] = new Option("Hockey", "hockey");
    dd.setAttribute("onchange", "GetSport(this.id)");
    cells[1].appendChild(dd);
    //Done
}

function GetSport(thisID)
{
  var table =  document.getElementById("Table1")
  var imageSRC = '';
  
  var elmnt = document.getElementById(thisID);
  // get currently selected option value
  var str = elmnt.options[elmnt.selectedIndex].value;
  
  // if else to set the image src
  if(str == 'soccer') { imageSRC = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-3d-printer-icon-set/256/Model.png'; }
  else if(str == 'basket') { imageSRC = 'https://dsfrc4icyn4oa.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/07134130/Approve-Sample-Hexa-Icon-250.png'; }
  else { imageSRC = 'http://nexticon.net/media/samples/check.png'; }
  
  // extract only the row number
  var x = thisID.replace("id", "");

  // throw in the variable with the dynamic image path
  table.rows[x - 1].cells[0].innerHTML = '<img src="' + imageSRC + '" width="20px" height="20px" />';
  //alert("The input value has changed. The new value is: " + val.id);
}
```

```css
#Table1
{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<table id="Table1">
<tr>
    <td colspan="12">OLD ROW</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction2()" value="add a new row" />
```

**EDIT:** I added the function `GetSport(thisID)` to the code and changed `dd.setAttribute("onchange", "GetSport(this)");` to `dd.setAttribute("onchange", "GetSport(this.id)");` in function `myFunction2()`, so the `select element` passes an `id` instead of `this`.

I added an example variable `imageSRC` and an `if-else` to make `different image paths` based on the `selected value`. You can use different approaches here like using an `array` to store the `paths`, or the pictures could be called for example soccer5135616.jpg basket894237582.jpg, etc.

Comment: I think this did the trick will need to do some mre testing as I encountered some error(with my code)  Thanks alot for help and comments in the code , will be off much help for a newbie. Ill comeback in a while for more comments .. cheers

Comment: OK so Ive tested it a little , so I updated forst post to include something ., Hope you dont mind

Comment: @Frederik84 I edited to include your function, also I added a couple lines of code to make the image change based on selected value. The edit is described at the bottom, where you click to run the snippet. Is this what you wanted? Oh, and the button and table are just there so we can test in different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks alot buddy you are a life saver for sure , This was exactly what I was after. I spent 16 hours yesterday trying to make this . I dont know anything about java scripts so it will take some time to get the hang of this. I especially appreciates you comments to your code. I did see you your: If-then statements, in vba coding one could use "select case" as an alternative to this , is that not supported in JS ? Also  I will need some time to test your edit but this looks great.  frederik

Comment: Ok so Im testing this not, the GetSport function is much better now ;) I dont understand how the old img gets deleted, where does that happen? Ive tested your if then statements and they does not return "Soccer", or "Bakset", They return Value1,Value2, Value3 I tried to change the code to reflect this but for some reeason it did not work.   hmmmm

Comment: I forgot to answer your question:. The table is supposed to be there but it has 15 columns. So It will take a long time before its finished based on how much time I've spent on the first Col. The buttons above the table maybe I will style later or change out I'm not sure yet,. In my excel sheet I use "ctrl + shift + a" / "ctrl + shift + d" to add or remove lines...

Comment: As Mosè Raguzzini suggested Ive created a link to codepen in first post . As you might see the img does not change. Also if you dont mind I have a couple of more questions. The header titles gets a little messed up by the empty Col, What is the best way to fix this. Also I really would like to make the select box a little bigger . Is that possible somehow ?

Comment: @Frederik84 `1.)` yes you can use switch statements as well. `2.)` The image doesn't get deleted, but rather switched by changing the `src` (source) of the image (`<img src="..." />`). `3.)` In this line of code you set the values of the select options `dd.options[dd.length] = new Option("Soccer", "soccer");`.  `4.)` Are the image and select element both supposed to be in the first column? `5.)` I see (code pen link you provided) the image changing when changing the selected option. `6.)` Give each `<th>` a width, the rest of the table (cells underneath) will follow those rules.

Comment: `7.)` you can give a width to the select element to make it wider. For example, inside the function `GetSport()` write `dd.style.width = '100px';` or similar. 8.) Your `<h1>` title in the code pen does not need a container `<div>`. You can simply erase the `<div>` and add the positioning and other `CSS` from the `div` to the `.title` `class`.

Comment: Hi thanks so much for all your comments and your time helping me with this. I was able to fix most of my problems actually . , Please note that your > If, elseif, else statement gave an error I  don't know why, but changing the [else] to [else if] fixed it.  Please see my updated Project files.  about your point #4. and Yes That is what I have landed on to get a cleaner look.

Comment: So now Im stuck with 2 problems:  #1 I (and this really frustrating) how to get the select box to show text on start up, I was thinking it should show "Soccer" - the way its now it comes up empty, #2 The .png seam to erase the the select box. I guess I could rebuilt it using techniques you showed me so far...,   frederik

Comment: @Frederik84 I fixed your code a little. I made too many changes to point them all out. The main ones are: 1.) I added a div inside cell 0 to align the picture and select element, the div is targeted by `cells[0].children[0]`. 2.) I gave each `<th>` their own width in `HTML` (must add up to 100%). So then the future column widths are prepared. 3.) other fixes to the code (missing semi columns, etc. ) and some `CSS` fixes (missing `.`, etc.)  Here is the code: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VygMWg](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VygMWg)

Comment: @Frederik84 If my answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted. Thanks, peace

Comment: Hi thanks alot for all your help. I really should mark this as triple solved :) I think I learned enough from you to continue on my own. In fact I was just able to add a jquery calendar to col 2. cheers .

Comment: @Frederik84 Your welcome and congratulations on the calendar :) I'm glad I was able to help. Peace

Comment: Its been marked sorry for the delay, I wish I could give you rep but it wasn't possible for my current level. ,, But thanks a lot again